# Automatically registering all ViewModel and View files

Tags: dryioc

I am looking into using DryIoc with Caliburn.Micro, and I could like to automatically register all ViewModels and Views.

In AutoFac you can do something like this

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AssemblySource.Instance.ToArray())
    .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("ViewModel"))
    .Where(type => type.GetInterface(ViewModelBaseType.Name, false) != null)
    .AsSelf()
    .InstancePerDependency();
```

Is there a similar way in DryIoc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equivalent code in DryIoc:

```
container.RegisterMany(AssemblySource.Instance.ToArray()
   .SelectMany(Portable.GetAssemblyTypes)
   .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("ViewModel"))
   .Where(type => type.GetInterface(ViewModelBaseType.Name, false) != null));
```

The default reuse will be Transient which is the same as `InstancePerDependency`.

**Update:**

There is also a bit simpler and more idiomatic alternative:

```
container.RegisterMany(AssemblySource.Instance,
    serviceTypeCondition: type => 
        type.Name.EndsWith("ViewModel") &&
        type.GetInterface(ViewModelBaseType.Name, false) != null);
```